# I need to multiply 2 UItextfields

Tags: swift, uitextfield, action, iboutlet

I created a bunch of text fields and buttons. Basically, I want to multiply the bill amount with the tip amount and divide the total amount by the number of people. I was thinking about making them variables but wasn't sure how to do it.

```
@IBOutlet weak var billAmount: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tipAmount: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var totalAmount: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfPeople: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var splitValue: UITextField!

@IBAction func splitBill(_ sender: UIButton) {
    splitValue.text = totalAmount / numberOfPeople
}

@IBAction func totalAmount(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let newBillAmount =
    totalAmount.text = billAmount * tipAmount
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to keep in mind that your IBOutlets are referencing UITextFields, not numbers.

So with this in mind, you need to be converting from strings to Doubles. This means that you can try and parse a Double from a string like so:

```
var text = String("5.0")
var double = Double(text)
print(double) // prints "5.0"
```

I have also made it "safe" for you in the sense that if the text is not a double, the if statement will not be executed, and thus you will not get runtime errors, just nothing will happen. This works in the same way for there being no "text" in the UITextFields, where the if-statement will not be executed, and you will just have the app do nothing.

Combining all of these things gives us something like this:

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var billAmount: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tipAmount: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalAmount: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfPeople: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var splitValue: UITextField!

    @IBAction func splitBill(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let totalAmountValue = Double(totalAmount.text!), let numberOfPeopleValue = Double(numberOfPeople.text!) { //safely get double values
            splitValue.text = String(totalAmountValue / numberOfPeopleValue) //convert the quotient of the doubles into a string
        }

    }

    @IBAction func totalAmount(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let billAmountValue = Double(billAmount.text!), let tipAmountValue = Double(tipAmount.text!) {
            totalAmount.text = String(billAmountValue * tipAmountValue)
        }

    }
}
```